# R - Error after library(plyr) command

Tags: r, twitter, plyr

I have Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon version and I'm using RStudio to do a sentiment analysis; I need to load the `plyr` package to do the analysis, but, when I run the commands in R:

```
library(twitteR)
library(plyr)
```

as described in this web [page](http://thinktostart.com/sentiment-analysis-on-twitter/), I get the following error:

```
Attaching package: ‘plyr’

The following object is masked from ‘package:twitteR’:

    id
```

Since browsing on the internet I did not find any solution to my problem, could someone of you help me?

It will be appreciated whether someone explains me the nature and the meaning of the error, in order to understand why I'm in wrong.

Comment: It is not an error, it is a warning, telling that the object `id` from package `twitteR` is masked by an object `id` from package `plyr`.

Comment: First of all, thanks @Pascal for your reply. So, according to you, if I go on the analysis it will not be any other problem?

Comment: There might be a problem, as `id` is not the same kind of object in `twitteR` and `plyr`.

Comment: Do you have some suggestion to avoid that or some way to recognizing the problem eventually, @Pascal ?

Comment: The best and crude way is to run your code and to check if errors occur.

Comment: Ok thanks. If you post an answer I will mark that, @Pascal

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it: Imagine there is a package A with object tmp and you
load it. When you load another package B with object of the same name i.e. tmp
then you will access tmp from package B and not A.